# Merging records from the same table

Tags: sql-server, database, data-integrity

I have a database which has contact details ranging from the unique contact id, name, address, city, zip ,phone, pager, cell, website and etc). I have noticed there are duplicate contacts (contact id is different first name and last name is same, some have other info missing where others have the info). I would like to merge the info if one row has a blank column and the other row does not. Is it possible that I can achieve this using the merge statement in MSSQL or is there another third party program that will merge data from records in a same table. I am confused as to how I would approach this. Help would be appreciated.

```
  contactid salutation  add1    add2    city    zip phone   officephone cellular    email   moddate contactrecordtype   contacttitleid  namefml
A00JL043                1 OPC           NYC     L6B 0J3   (123)456-789               admin@admin.com    06/17/2011 0:00   CONTACT      MCGUNTY ALISON 
A00JL6L2                                 LA     L9H 7N5                    (123)456-789  admin@admin.com    06/17/2011 0:00   CONTACT       MCGUNTY ALISON 
A00JL9Z9               1 OPC             LA     L9H 7N5     (123)456-789    (123)456-789 admin@admin.com    06/20/2011 0:00 CONTACT             MCGUNTY ALISON 
A00JM5AZ                                                    LA  L9H 7N5     (123)456-789    (123)456-789                            admin@admin.com 06/24/2011 0:00 CONTACT             MCGUNTY ALISON 
A00JP8FW                                                    LA  L9H 7N5                             (123)456-789                            admin@admin.com 07/18/2011 0:00 CONTACT WORKER  MCGUNTY ALISON 
A00JQZ0Q                    SUITE 300                       LA      6589503     (   )    -              admin@admin.com 08/02/2011 0:00 CONTACT STUDENT MCGUNTY ALISON 
A00JT9AD                                                    LA      (   )    -                  (   )    -              admin@admin.com 08/17/2011 0:00 CONTACT     MCGUNTY ALISON 
A00K5ZJ9                                                    LA                                                          admin@admin.com 11/01/2011 0:00 CONTACT     MCGUNTY ALISON 
A00KMQ67    MS.         1 OPC   SUITE 100                       LA  L9H 7N5     (   )    -                  (   )    -              admin@admin.com 03/20/2012 0:00 CONTACT     MCGUNTY ALISON 
A00KPL1V                        LA  L9H 7N5     (   )    -              (123)456-789    12658962    tor@check.com   NULL    CONTACT     MCGUNTY ALISON 
A00KUT7A                                                    LA  L9H 7N5                             (123)456-789                                NULL    CONTACT WORKER  MCGUNTY ALISON
```

Comment: Do a set difference (as per your business rules) on the two tables and insert only ones that don't already exist?  Seems like really basic SQL...

Comment: Agreed, it seems that the OP has never touched SQL, for he/she would be able to do this...

Comment: I am not looking for differences between two tables. I am looking for a way to merge all information related to a contact from the same table (i.e multiple records merging into 1). Example, there are 10 contacts with the same last name and first name all with different information and some with the same information, some blank and some filled out. How would you go about merging this. I can do set differences that's not a problem. The problem is how would you compare them and say take email from 1 where there are conflicting emails and etc.

Comment: Please read carefully before replying to questions asked by users.

Comment: @user3470756 - you need to give us some table structure sample rows etc. Makes it easy for people to help. That is how SO works.

Comment: Please see above. Not sure exactly why the format is not coming in correctly. This may be a bad example. But will provide an overview of the data I'm trying to merge into 1 master one and then delete the other duplicates. Essentially the end goal is to perform data clean up.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-design your table structure with a proper Normalization (Eliminate data redundancy) I would delete duplicate data, use this link to delete duplicated data in the tables, hope this was helpfull http://www.dfarber.com/computer-consulting-blog/2011/12/26/remove-duplicate-records-in-sql.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I've read this article. But it doesn't really explain how I would go about doing this. And re-designing isn't an option here. IT contains over years and years of data.

Comment: For troubleshooting, create a dummy table with duplicated rows based on your scenario and use this example very explainable  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/23/sql-server-2005-2008-delete-duplicate-rows/